# !Join in Serverless Framework is broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

```
  RetrieveAllSubscribersLambdaPermissionApiGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: { "Fn::GetAtt": [ RetrieveAllSubscribersLambdaFunction, Arn ] }
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: 
        !Join
          - "/"
          - - 'arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:12345'
          - - 'other stuff'
```

I have this block of code where I try and get a `sourceArn` for this block. I realize the sourceArn is invalid in this example, but so is the viewed output from Serverless.

```
An error occurred: RetrieveAllSubscribersLambdaPermissionApiGateway - 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:12345/aws/:execute-api:/us-west-2/:/12345/:/a5dghhjk9//*/*' at 'sourceArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z0-9-]*):([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+:([a-z]{2}((-gov)|(-iso(b?)))?-[a-z]+-\d{1})?:(\d{12})?:(.*) (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: a8db5326-dcdd-4abc-b4ae-e4fa5c03c6bd; Proxy: null).
```

Comment: Were is the rest of your join? You are not joining anything in your example.

Comment: @Marcin I added a second line, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Submitted a bug report - https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/10519

Comment: With a valid `sourceArn`, what does it output (if anything)?

Comment: If I hardcode the sourceArn, it works fine. The challenge is interpolating the api gateway id into the string. 6 hours into debugging this.

Comment: It's still a bit early to call it a bug. I'm taking a look and at first glance, it just looks like a reference to the gateway is the problem. I need the entirety of the `serverless.yaml` to see if that's actually the case. Could you post that either here or on your ticket (I'm following both)?

Comment: Let me share a repo, that might be easiest. I'll update here and on report in a couple minutes.

Comment: @Urmzd - https://github.com/Schachte/ServerlessLambdaSetup

Comment: Relevant reference file is https://github.com/Schachte/ServerlessLambdaSetup/blob/master/resources/iam/UserRetrievalLambdaPolicy.yml#L1

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look and maybe we should move this chat to the issue.

Comment: Sounds good, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- Update 2022/01/16 12:49 AM
The problem was indeed with the tags. Everything can be seen on the issue. TLDR; use the full function name (e.g. 'Fn::Join').

However, I'm almost certain that the shorthand can work, there are just some conditions that need to be met first. I will not investigate, since a working solution for the original problem has been achieved and anything else would be outside the scope.

-- Original
After some back and forth between Ryan and myself. Ryan used an alternative solution involving `!Sub` and the `serverless-cloudformation-sub-variables` plugin which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/10519).

In short, the problem likely lied in dependencies involving tags not correctly being resolved (most likely due to misconfigurations. Still investigating and will update if the original solution can be resolved with additional plugins).

The following plugin abstracts the use of `!Sub` which in turn resolved the issue,
[serverless-cloudformation-sub-variables](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-cloudformation-sub-variables)